# Where can I get a list of stale RBF'd transactions?

Tags: mempool, replace-by-fee

I would like to prove that a certain transaction was in the mempool on a certain date before it got replaced via RBF with another transaction. Is there any service that provides this data?

Comment: Don't know about any service, but if you are running with `debug=mempool` you can grep your `debug.log` for `replacing tx <original txid>`.

Comment: I'm assuming you don't want to prove it e.g. cryptographically?

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to prove that a certain transaction was in the mempool on a certain date before it got replaced via RBF with another transaction.

Consider Tx `de8ba282831c6d645aa777a35a5b9f2107cbd96913a9cd4c5880420db092e399` as an example.

`gettransaction`in Bitcoin Core returns:

```
"time": 1615601043,
"timereceived": 1615601043,
"replaced_by_txid": "f77e6928c1c12bc91858c95b32dab1e493b24cdf3e19c02372aa11e6dc5ec3c9",
```

Time of this tx: Saturday, March 13, 2021 2:04:03 AM

Got replaced by [another tx](https://tbtc.bitaps.com/c44cca7864271775d648ace0ccdb377247840000ed74a8af0301ce7cc92c3a29) on: Saturday, March 13, 2021 2:04:11 AM

I am not sure but maybe this information is only available for transactions that belong to your wallet because no other RPC returns  `replaced_by_txid`.

> Is there any service that provides this data?

Couldn't find such information in any of the famous bitcoin explorers. Best I could find was one explorer that shows `invalid` type for tx which got replaced:

https://tbtc.bitaps.com/de8ba282831c6d645aa777a35a5b9f2107cbd96913a9cd4c5880420db092e399

Comment: I think it doesn't correctly answer the question as the OP asks about "a transaction from my mempool" and `gettransaction` is only about transactions from our wallet.

Comment: 1. `gettransaction` is only for wallet transactions which is the only RPC that returns `replaced_by_txid` so it's not possible to check if Tx2 transaction was replacement for Tx1 2. OP is looking for a certain transaction that "was in the mempool" but "got replaced". Got replaced = Got included in block or again replaced until confirmed.